# Firebase Firestore: Cannot delete document due to TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my Angular app, I am trying to delete a document from my Firestore database using the `delete()` method, but it's not working. The document ID is retrieved correctly and logged in the console, but when I try to delete it, I get an error. I have tried different solutions, but none of them worked. Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

this is my function code:

```
  async deleteArticle(article: Article) {
    const confirmed = confirm('are you sure you want to delete the article ' + article.title + '?');
    if (confirmed) {
      try {
        const docRef = this.db.collection('articles').doc(article.id);
        console.log("this is the ID I want to delete: " + docRef.id);
        await docRef.delete();
        console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error deleting article: ", error);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tried the following solutions:

- Using the deleteDoc() method instead of delete().
- Wrapping the document ID with String() method.
- Making sure that the document ID is not null or undefined.
- Checking the Firestore rules to make sure that the user has the necessary permissions to delete the document.

What I expected was that the document would be deleted successfully and the console would log "Document successfully deleted!". However, the delete() method didn't seem to work, and I got an error instead. The document ID was retrieved correctly and logged in the console, but the document was not deleted.

Comment: Did you try: `const docRef = this.db.collection('articles'); docRef.doc(article.id).delete();`? Doesn't seem to be much different than what you did, but doesn't hurt to try. Btw, do your other CRUD methods work?

Comment: @MishaMashina thanks for answering, but I tried this and it didn't work:(
the other crud works fine.

Comment: "I get an error" Please edit your question to show the exact error message **and the entire stack trace** that you get.

Comment: Fix it.
It was a typo on my firebase property.